# Cannot load modules/mod_ssl.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so: undefined symbol: ap_array_str_contains

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, mod-ssl

I am trying to run Apache on Amazon Linux with SSL for my website and I configured all ssl prerequisites. But when I start the Apache it throws the error saying:

```
Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 58 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-ssl.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_ssl.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so: undefined symbol: ap_array_str_contains
```

conf.modules.d/00-ssl.conf file contains:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

Apache httpd version:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.12 (Amazon)
```

I installed mod_ssl using:

```
yum install mod24_ssl
```

I am not aware how to troubleshoot this; I am pretty new to apache.

Please help me if anyone would came across the similar issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My hunch would be that the SSL module has been compiled against a different version of Apache than the one trying to load it, given that version 2.4.12 of Apache was released in January 2015 and I can see reference to adding the function `ap_array_str_contains()` to `server/util.c` in the Apache source only in September 2015.

What does `rpm -q mod24_ssl httpd(*)` return? They should both realistically have the same version.

(*) Amazon Linux might name their Apache package slightly differently.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Is there any possibility to upgrade Apache and install right version of mod24_ssl without affecting the application?

Comment: Output of "rpm -q mod24_ssl httpd*"
mod24_ssl-2.4.18-1.64.amzn1.x86_64
package httpd* is not installed

Comment: As suspected, you've somehow managed to install a newer version of mod_ssl for the version of Apache you have. You need to install/upgrade `httpd` (or that might be `httpd24`) so they're both version 2.4.18.

Comment: Yes, the issue is with Amazon Linux doesn't support mod24_ssl-2.4.12 right now.  I just installed httpd24- 2.4.18 then it works. `**$ yum --showduplicates list mod24_ssl | expand**
Available Packages
mod24_ssl.x86_64                  1:2.4.18-1.64.amzn1                  amzn-main                              **$  yum --showduplicates list httpd24 | expand**
Installed Packages
httpd24.x86_64                   2.4.12-1.60.amzn1                    @amzn-main
Available Packages
httpd24.x86_64                   2.4.18-1.64.amzn1                    amzn-main`